# Migrate web forms ASP.NET Membership OpenAuth for Google from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-membership, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I have an existing web forms site that utilizes the built-in ASP.NET Membership OpenAuth model. All has worked well for over a year and a half, but I just found out that Google has deprecated OpenID 2.0 and will shut it down on April 20, 2015 (just over a week).

This is where abstraction really bites you in the ass, because all I have is a single line of code in my AuthConfig.cs

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();
```

I've updated all of my OpenAuth related NuGet packages, hoping that there was a fix for this under the covers - but no joy.

Is there an easy solution for this, or do I need to completely strip out and rewrite the Google authentication piece?

(Lots of questions related to this, but I haven't found anything specifically related to the web forms Membership.OpenAuth implementation.)

Comment: I think you may have to write it. I just recently wrote one for OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient using DotNotOpenAuth

Answer (score 2):

The Nuget package "[DotNetOpenAuth OAuth2 Client for Google](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2/)" solved this for me.

In AuthConfig.cs, replace `OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();` with:

```
var client = new GoogleOAuth2Client(clientID, clientSecret);
var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.Add("Google", () => client, extraData);
```

Get the string values clientID and clientSecret by [setting up your Google App](http://benfoster.io/blog/oauth-providers#google).

In the page responding to the redirect Uri you register with Google, add `GoogleOAuth2Client.RewriteRequest()` before your existing call to `OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication(redirectUrl)`.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. I tried the approach above, but still keep getting the error "Too many redirects." Is there an updated "Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.dll" file out there that solves the Google OpenID Connect problem?